# Controller File Won't Show up in Project

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am building a C# mvc web application. All of the links are working so the controller file must be there, however I can't find it in the project. Any ideas of what is happening?

Comment: what do you mean? while controller file? eg HomeController, ValuesController?
I think there is normally a folder called Controllers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you need to click the **show all files** in the Solution Explorer. [image]